# How to return token in account manager

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I very bad understand the authentication process on Android. I write a custom authenticator:

```
public class Authenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    private final Context mContext;

    public Authenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                             String accountType,
                             String authTokenType,
                             String[] requiredFeatures,
                             Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AuthActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
        intent.putExtra(AuthActivity.KEY_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
        intent.putExtra(AuthActivity.KEY_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                               Account account,
                               String authTokenType,
                               Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);
        String authToken = am.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            final String password = am.getPassword(account);

            if (password != null) {
                //authToken = sServerAuthenticate.userSignIn(account.name, password, authTokenType);
            }
        } else {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
            return result;
        }

        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
        intent.putExtra(AuthActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        intent.putExtra(AuthActivity.KEY_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

I didn't write stub methods.

 After I try to register a new account:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this);
Account account = new Account("username", vcs.getAccountType());
accountManager.getAuthToken(account, "oauth", null, MainActivity.this,
      new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {}
      },
      new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  return false;
            }
     }));
```

All works and I got token from server but... How to return this token in the account manager from Authentication activity?

It's my AuthActivity code:

```
public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = AuthActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "account_type";
    public static final String KEY_AUTH_TYPE = "auth_type";
    public static final String KEY_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT = "new_account";
    public VCS mB = new B();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(mB.getAccessRequest()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

In `onNewIntent` I get auth token.